# inline asm: operand type mismatch for 'out'

Tags: c++, x86, g++, inline-assembly, hardware-port

I don't know assembly in depth. Following code is for writing to hardware port.

Compiler gives operand type mismatch error in every line where inline asm is used.When I compile I get these errors:

> ```
> port.cpp: Assembler messages:  
> port.cpp:27: Error: operand type mismatch for 'out'
> port.cpp:34: Error: operand type mismatch for 'in' 
> port.cpp:51: Error: operand type mismatch for 'out' 
> port.cpp:69: Error: operand type mismatch for 'out' 
> port.cpp:75: Error: operand type mismatch for 'in' 
> port.cpp:94: Error: operand type mismatch for 'out' 
> port.cpp:100: Error: operand type mismatch for 'in'
> ```

**port.h**

```
#ifndef __PORT_H
#define __PORT_H

#include "types.h"


class Port
{
    protected:
        Port(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port();
        uint16_t portnumber;
};


class Port8Bit : public Port
{
    public:
        Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port8Bit();

        virtual uint8_t Read();
        virtual void Write(uint8_t data);
};



class Port8BitSlow : public Port8Bit
{
    public:
        Port8BitSlow(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port8BitSlow();

        virtual void Write(uint8_t data);
};



class Port16Bit : public Port
{
    public:
        Port16Bit(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port16Bit();

        virtual uint16_t Read();
        virtual void Write(uint16_t data);
};



class Port32Bit : public Port
{
    public:
        Port32Bit(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port32Bit();

        virtual uint32_t Read();
        virtual void Write(uint32_t data);
};

#endif
```

**port.cpp**

```
#include "port.h"


Port::Port(uint16_t portnumber)
{
    this->portnumber = portnumber;
}

Port::~Port()
{
}



Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
    : Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port8Bit::~Port8Bit()
{
}

void Port8Bit::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1" :: "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber));
}

uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()
{
    uint8_t result;
    __asm__ volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber));   
    return result;
}



Port8BitSlow::Port8BitSlow(uint16_t portnumber)
    : Port8Bit(portnumber)
{
}

Port8BitSlow::~Port8BitSlow()
{
}

void Port8BitSlow::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1\njmp 1f\n1: jmp 1f\n1:" :: "a" (data),       "Nd" (portnumber));
}





Port16Bit::Port16Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
    : Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port16Bit::~Port16Bit()
{
}

void Port16Bit::Write(uint16_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outw %0, %1" :: "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber));
}

uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()
{
    uint16_t result;
    __asm__ volatile("inw %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber));   
    return result;
}





Port32Bit::Port32Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
    : Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port32Bit::~Port32Bit()
{
}

void Port32Bit::Write(uint32_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outl %0, %1" :: "a" (data), "Nd"   (portnumber));
}

uint32_t Port32Bit::Read()
{
    uint32_t result;
    __asm__ volatile("inl %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber));   
   return result;
}
```

How can i correct it? Is there anything wrong with structure of program?

Comment: Can you show us how `portnumber` is declared in your class?

Comment: You have likely defined `portnumber` to be something other than `uint16_t`. The register _DX_ has to be used (not _EDX_, _RDX_ or _DL_).

Comment: You may be able to solve your problem if you change  `"Nd" (portnumber)` to `"Nd" ((uint16_t)portnumber)`, or change `portnumber` to be a `uint16_t` or modify `%1` to be `%w1`. I'd personally change the type of `portnumber` to uint16_t.

Comment: What is happening is that when the compiler sees the constraint `"Nd"` it may choose to use the `d` register (that can be either of DL, DX, EDX, RDX). The way the compiler decided which variant of the register to use is by the type of the value in the constraint - in this case `portnumber`. If `portnumber` is uint8_t it would use DL and if it was uint32_t it would have used EDX.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thank you for your comment. I have declared `portnumber`  as `uint16_t` in base `class port`. I have edited the post to include files.

Comment: Are you saying you still have a problem? If this code you posted now doesn't work then I have to assume you defined `uint16_t` improperly. You didn't show the file `types.h` . It should be an `unsigned short int`. I assume this is for OSdev?

Comment: The typedef for uint16_t would look something like `typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;` where a `short` in your environment would be 16-bits wide.

Comment: While I agree with Michael's diagnosis, if the uint16_t definitions look correct, you might also try adding `-S` to the build line.  This will cause the compiler to generate port.s, which will contain the actual assembly generated for your code.  Edit that file and search for these asm lines and post the exact code here.  You might also try his suggestion of replacing the `%1` with `%w1`.

Comment: Did you ever get this going?

Comment: You are right. The problem was in definition of `uint16_t`. I have now defined it as `typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;` and its working. Thank you very much for your comments. These comments helped me in better understanding of inline assembly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP never showed `types.h` but the followup comments only suggested that one real possibility existed and that was `uint16_t` was not defined as a 16-bit type. On x86/x86-64 such a type can be defined with:

```
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;
```

The errors come about because in order to choose a register for an extended inline assembly template GCC uses the size of the type passed in the constraint to determine if the register chosen should be a 16/32/64 bit register. If the size is not 16-bits the wrong size register will be chosen and the generated assembly will have an operand mismatch.

In this case apparently the OP improperly specified a wrong size type when he created his own `uint16_t` definition. Port commands (in, out etc) only take *DX* (16-bit) as register operand, not *EDX*, or *RDX* or *DL*. If the register generated was not *DX* the code would have compiled/assembled with the error the OP was seeing.